# Automated Html IDs: No good when users disable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using JavaScript, I have this function to automatically assign IDs to my HTML body tags for every document on my website, like so:

```
$(function(){
        var pathname=window.location.pathname; 
        var getLast=pathname.match(/.*\/(.*)$/)[1]; 
        var truePath=getLast.replace(".php","");
        if(truePath===''){
        $('body').attr('id', 'index');
        }else{
        $('body').attr('id', truePath);}
    });
```

Then I style the document using CSS with the body tags like so:

```
#index p {color:green;}
#about p {color:blue;}
#faq p {color:red;}
#contact p {color:yellow;}
```

But this will be of no relevance if the user disables JavaScript, because all the styling will be lost.

How can I get around this for non-JavaScript users while adding the IDs to body tags automatically?

Comment: You're obviously using PHP, so what keeps you from doing it on the server side?

Comment: Server side? I'm sorry, I didn't know this could be done server side. Thanks a clean break. Thank you. I'll google the rest. However if I was using only html, would there be a way to work around this?

Comment: If you're working with 1 html file per page then you'd manually edit them to add id's to the body tags?

Comment: What's the situation that javascript disabled by the user?　maybe we can get different answers with discussing the situation

Comment: I learned that JavaScript should be used as an enhancement to your website, not an essential. If your target audience covers worldwide scope then it's obvious you should code your website for non-JavaScript users no matter their reasons or circumstances.